# How do you show or hide a decoration view in a custom flow layout?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I implemented a flow layout that has a sticky decoration view on top. This is achieved by subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout and overriding the following methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
    return YES;
}
```

and

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSMutableArray *result = [[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect] mutableCopy];
    [result addObject:[self stickyHeaderLayoutAttributes]];

    return result;
}
```

(Internally, the decoration view's layout attribtues are stored as a property and -stickyHeaderLayoutAttributes updates its frame to always appear on top of collection view).

Now I have a toggle button on the navigation bar of the collection view controller that displays some data using the custom flow layout. One tap on the toggle button should hide the decoration view by sliding it under the navigation bar. A second tap should reveal it (again, sliding from under the navigation bar).

My approach for hiding the decoration view is the following (it works in a similar way for showing it):

1. When tapping the button, tell the layout to hide the decoration view, e.g. by setting a flag.
2. Invoke

   ```
    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];
   ```
3. In *layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:* do not pass layout attributes for the decoration view.
4. *finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:* is invoked, I set the frame to be under the navigation bar.
5. The collection view removes the decoration view and slides it under the navigation bar.

What I noticed, though, is that just with step 2., *finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:* gets called, which means the decoration view *should* be removed.

Why is this happening?

*indexPathsToDeleteForSupplementaryViewOfKind:* returns an empty array, therefore it is not really clear to me why the decoration view should be removed.

Is there a better approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to remove the Decoration view you can use removeFromSuperview.

I show a collectionView nested in a container view and use the following to remove the decoration view (BGSScheduleDecorationView):

```
- (IBAction)butAction1:(id)sender
{
    for (UIView *view in self.myCollectionVC.collectionView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[BGSScheduleDecorationView class]])
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that does not give you the chance to animate the removal of the decoration view right?

Comment: This approach simply removes the decoration view without any animation.  I use it to switch off an initial grid backdrop.